# Eclipse won't recognize an import to a referenced library of another project on the build path

Tags: java, eclipse

Pretty much as the title says: I have two projects. One of them has a referenced library with a class called, say, com.foo.Bar. So then in my other project I have the first project on the build path, and I try to import com.foo.Bar.
 That should work, but eclipse doesn't recognize it, even after I save and run it. Any idea on how to fix that?
(And not just "add the library to the build path of the second project.")

Comment: How do you know "add the library to the build path of the second project." isn't the answer (P.S., it **is** the answer). Adding a project to the build path doesn't necessarily add all transitive dependencies.

Comment: It doesn't? I thought it did... Oops. Anyway, I was just hoping there was a different solution, because they both need the library.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from adding the library to both projects if they both need it. If you're wanting transitive dependencies and such, you might look at converting your project to use Maven and then import the Maven project into eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the **Java Build Path** property page of the first project, you would need to [Export](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm?cp=1_4_9_0_0_0) that library entry to make it visible to other projects that depend on the first project.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I wonder why this answer hasn't been accepted yet...

Comment: For all newbies: This can be done via right-click on your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export > select the libraries you want to export.